# Calculating commission

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1054, mysql-error-1111

I am trying to calculate commissions payable to clients at the beginning of every month (providing their commission is more then £25).

Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT  SUM(invoiceCommision) as totalSum
FROM    tbl_statement_items
WHERE   fk_rid = '1'
  AND   dt > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
  AND   totalSum > 25;
```

However when I run this, mysql says: 1054 - Unknown column 'totalSum' in 'where clause'.

I then tried

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_statement_items
WHERE   fk_rid = '1'
  AND   dt > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
  AND   SUM(invoiceCommision) > 25;
```

This gives me error: 1111 - Invalid use of group function.

I am stumped on this one, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Someone did answer and it worked, but their answer disappeared :S, Thank you if it was you. Would accept it but ovs cant.

Comment: But you can post an answer yourself with what they gave you and then accept it (though I think there may be a time interval you need to wait). This gives the thread an answer, closes it out, and allows anyone else that comes along the solution.

Comment: @Brad: The thread has an answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first attempt, it didn't work because you can't use the computed fields in your SELECT clause in your WHERE clause (WHERE is processed before the fields are computed).

For the second attempt, it didn't work because you can't use aggregate functions in the WHERE clause. Again, just stick to your first attempt but change WHERE to HAVING.

There is also a more general problem that your SUM() function will just get the total sum of all statement items, whereas you want it per client. You can use GROUP BY to get a list of sums per client, and a HAVING clause to only return those with a sum greater than 25.

Try this (change client_id to whatever it really is):

```
SELECT client_id, SUM(invoiceCommision) as totalSum
FROM tbl_statement_items
WHERE fk_rid = '1' AND dt > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY client_id
HAVING totalSum > 25;
```

Comment: SELECT fk_rid, SUM(invoiceCommision) as totalSum
FROM tbl_statement_items
WHERE fk_rid = '1' AND dt > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
GROUP BY fk_rid. You code works alot better then the previous one thank you +1
HAVING totalSum > 25;

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell MySQL how to group the data when using grouping functions such as `SUM`

I expect you require something like this:

```
SELECT *, SUM(invoiceCommision) as commisionSum
FROM tbl_statement_items 
WHERE fk_rid = '1' 
    AND dt > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
GROUP BY fk_rid 
HAVING commisionSum > 25;
```

You must use the `HAVING` function when you require `GROUP` based conditions such as `SUM`, `MAX` etc

Comment: Where is `invoiceCommision` defined? Is it a column in your `tbl_statement_items ` table?

Comment: Yes invoiceCommision is in the tbl_statement_items

Comment: No it wasn't and yes it worked for me, the code was (for ref): SELECT SUM(invoiceCommision) as totalSum FROM tbl_statement_items WHERE fk_rid = '1' AND dt > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) HAVING totalSum > 25;

Comment: This didn't work because it still has an aggregate function (SUM()) in the WHERE clause, which is not allowed.